# Bigquery - Temporal Table

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

How can i create a temporal table in Bigquery to store historical data from another table? i didn't find a useful syntax,
for example i have table-1 which contain data of users, in this table i have coulmn that will show 1 if they were active for the last 30 days, but after 30 days i lose this information and i can't say in March we have 30 users who were active, so i need to store this as historical table, will appreciate your help